# Spoofing iPhone location in Xcode using code

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, geolocation

For a school project I'm trying to spoof my iPhone's location using code. I already know about the Debug > Simulate Location option, but I was wondering if I can somehow spoof it using either a framework or passing GPX data through code or something similar.

For example, in Android you can simply do:

```
location.setLatitude(latitude); 
location.setLongitude(longitude);
```

Is this possible in Xcode/Xamarin too?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MkMapView's setRegion function

```
 let region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(selectedLocationCoordinate, 1000, 1000)
 mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

Here selectedLocationCoordinate is of type CLLocationCoordinate2D and you can specify its latitude and longitude by using its latitude and longitude property

```
 selectedLocationCoordinate.latitude =  

 selectedLocationCoordinate.longitude =
```

Comment: Thanks! As I am just a beginner with Xcode, can you give me a example of what 'selectedLocationCoordinate' should look like?

Comment: It can be like   let selectedLocationCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)

Comment: yes, I can see manually given long/lat coords on my MapView. But it's not changing the iPhone's location. Just on the map only.

Comment: Where are you checking the iPhone's location, other than the map ?

Comment: If I open Safari Maps I see my current location. Lets say I live in city A, and in my code I've set my location to city B. It's still showing A.

Comment: Oh man I'm sorry I thought you need to set the current location in the MkMapView in your app. I'm sorry but I didn't understand what you are referring to as safari map?
Is it the default map application that you are referring to ?

Comment: Refer to this https://blackpixel.com/writing/2013/05/simulating-locations-with-xcode.html I'm not sure whether this will help you or not.